# How can I verify what is being matched by regex?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

In the following:

```
~$ perl -e '  
my $var = "March 1998";  
$var =~ /([0-9]*)/;  
print "$1\n";
```

Nothing is printed. I could not understand why, but after thinking about it a bit, I think that it matches just not the number part since it needs 0 or more occurrences of a number and the whole line satisfies that. But how can I actually see/"capture" what it actually matches to verify my assumption>

Comment: How about using `$&` ? But if you want to check if it matches at least 1 number, you need to use `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: I think you want `[0-9]+` which is more commonly written as `\d+`.

Comment: Someone with more time can explain this better, but the issue is the `*`. It means "zero or more times" and it's greedy. So, it matches one of those numbers zero times and calls it a day. The result of the match is "true" ... but the capture is empty (zero times). `+` is "one or more" so you get the `1998` in the capture.

Comment: note that you should always check if the match succeeded before looking at `$1` or any of the other match variables.

Comment: @ysth this match will succeed, with $1 being empty.

Comment: To visually debug it, try [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Debugger) `perl -MRegexp::Debugger -e 'my $var = "March 1998";  $var =~ /([0-9]*)/;  print "$1\n";'`

Comment: Yes, I know it will; nevertheless, not checking for success is bad practice.

Comment: `-Mre=debug` aka `use re 'debug';` will show how the regex is matching.

Comment: @ikegami `-Mre=debug` Cool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$1` contains what is captured, so you're doing that right.

The special variables `$'`, `$&`, and `` $` `` will also be helpful. See [`perlvar`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar) for more information.

```
$match = $var =~ /([0-9]*)/;

print "There ", ($match ? "was" : "was not"), " a match\n";
print "The captured expression was '$1'\n";
print "The matched expression was '$&'\n";  # includes chars outside capture groups
print "Expression before the match was '$`'\n";
print "Expression after the match was '$''\n";
```

Starting with Perl 5.10, you can also use the `/p` modifier and the more readable `${^PREMATCH}`, `${^MATCH}`, `${^POSTMATCH}` variables.

```
$match = $var =~ /([0-9]*)/p;

print "There ", ($match ? "was" : "was not"), " a match\n";
print "The captured expression was '$1'\n";
print "The matched expression was '${^MATCH}'\n";
print "Expression before the match was '${^PREMATCH}'\n";
print "Expression after the match was '${^POSTMATCH}'\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned, never examine `$1`, `$2`, etc. without checking that the match succeeded.  Otherwise, those variables will contain whatever they contained after the most recent successful regex match.  An exception is when the regex can match any string--as yours can, though you probably didn't realize it--but that kind of situation is rare, and it's better to get into the habit of always testing the success of the match.

The [`@-`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@LAST_MATCH_START) and [`@+`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@LAST_MATCH_END) variables give the beginning and ending indexes (respectively) of the matching capturing groups in the string that was the object of the previous successful regex match.

```
if ($var =~ /([0-9]*)/) {
    print "The first capturing group matched from index $-[1] to index $+[1].\n";
}
```

This prints `The first capturing group matched from index 0 to index 0.`  Sure enough, your string begins with zero digits, so that's what was matched.